# Do the official USAV rules for coed volleyball require a female touch?

Tags: rules, volleyball

Is there an official USAV rule that states that in coed, indoors, 6-versus-6 volleyball, at least one of the 3 touches allowed by a team has to be done by a girl?

My league has stated that if no girl touches the ball we lose a point, because that is the official USAV rule. Is that true?

Comment: It's not a bad rule. It simply keeps guys from 'playing around' girls on the team. Face it, you know guys who would do that.Play reverse Coed...much better for female hitters...and male setters like myself :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  When playing co-ed indoor volleyball (also called Mixed Six), anytime your team has more than one hit, one of the hits, not including blocking, must be made by a female.

There is also a provision in the rulebook for "reverse co-ed" (reverse Mixed Six) where one of the touches must be made by a male.

From the [2013-2015 Domestic Competition Regulations](https://volleyballreftraining.com/rules_interpretations_indoor.php), Co-Ed Rules (page 108):

> 1.2 When the ball is played more than once by a team,
>   a female player shall make at least one of the contacts. Contact of the ball during blocking shall not
>   constitute playing the ball. There is no requirement
>   for a male player to contact the ball, regardless of
>   the number of hits by a team.
>
> 1.2.1 If a team contacts the ball more than one
>   time during offensive action, one of the
>   contacts must be by a female player, but
>   there is no restriction preventing all three
>   team hits from being made by female players. Contact of the ball during blocking action does not count as one of the three team
>   hits. Therefore, after a block, a male player
>   may play the ball back over the net as such
>   contact would be considered the first team hit.
>
> 1.2.2 A ball contacted more than once by a team,
>   without a female player having contacted
>   it, remains live and does not become an
>   illegal hit until it fully crosses the plane of
>   the net or is contacted by an opponent.
>
> 1.2.3 An illegally hit ball blocked by an illegal blocker
>   results in a double fault, and a playover is
>   directed.